# DownloadManager images not showing in gallery

Tags: android

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I have the following code as a Download Listener for my webview. When an image is downloaded via this it shows in the Files app but doesn't show in the Google Photos app.

The `request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()` is depreciated and when I change the directory to DIRECTORY_PICTURES I can't see the image in files at all.

My images are all JPEGS and an interesting note is that all of the images that show in Google Photos have under details documents/msf:int compared to my downloaded images which are just documents/msf. Also, when I rename my photos that the Download Manager has downloaded, they appear within Google Photos.

```kotlin
webview.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength ->
    // Getting data
    val filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)
    val cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)

    // Setting up Download Request Manager
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request
        .setMimeType(mimeType)
        .addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies)
        .addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
        .setTitle(filename)
        .setDescription("Taken from RPI")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename)

    // Setting up Main Download Manager
    val manager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    manager.enqueue(request)

    generateSnack(view, filename)  // Ignore this, just makes a snackbar with the filename
```

How can I get my images downloaded using my Download Manager to show in the gallery?

Comment: request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); ?

Comment: You can always invoke the mediascanner yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, that method is deprecated. How would I invoke it myself?

Comment: It's strange how it is missing the `msf:int` under the document ID...

Comment: What does it matter that it is deprecated when it works? Its no sinn using it! Does reboot the device help?

Comment: I figured it out - it was to do with the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

For some reason, images with certain characters just refuse to show in `Google Photos` BUT they will still show in `Files`.

My specific case example was that my file names were the following: "day-month-year#int". For example one of them was "14-11-20#2" because it was the second photo taken on that day.

As soon as I removed the hashtag character it all worked and automatically appeared in Google photos. Also, the "msf:int" still doesn't appear even with this but that doesn't concern me.